# base_row_total in email template - total price issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I'm creating an email transactional template and I noticed my total isn't showing the 19.89 cents. the code is what I'm using below in my Items.phtml

```
'total' => $wa_data['symbol'] . ' ' . intval($vars['_data']['base_row_total']),
```

then in my template I'm using this,

```
<?php echo($_item['total'] ); ?>
```

How do I get the price to be 19.89 showing the cents instead of just dollar account?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to change this, simply change the intval to floatval and it shows correctly like this here,

```
'total' => $wa_data['symbol'] . ' ' . floatval($vars['_data']['base_row_total']),
```